# Importing/Using p5.Sound into React

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I'm trying to get p5.sound into my React app, after having successfully gotten p5.js canvas functionality working.

I have a p5Wrapper for my p5 sketch.  And as I said the canvas functionality works great(ish).  But, I'm unable to get the sound functionality into either the parent component, the wrapper, or the sketch itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have p5.js, p5.sound, and p5.dom all local in my repo.  And here are the component, wrapper, and sketch I'm working with....

THE COMPONENT

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import Style from "../oogles/oogles.scss";
    import P5Wrapper from "../../../wrappers/P5Wrapper";
    import Oogle from "../oogles/sketch.js";

    class Oogles extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                sketch : Oogle
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            console.log("oogles");

        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="oogle">
                <h1>Oogles</h1>
                    <P5Wrapper sketch={this.state.sketch} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Oogles;
```

THE WRAPPER:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import Style from "../wrappers/wrapper.scss";
    import p5 from 'p5';
    import "../../p5/addons/p5.sound.js";


    class P5Wrapper extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                parentW: window.innerWidth,
                parentH: '',
            };
            this.updateCanvasDimensions = this.updateCanvasDimensions.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount(){        
            this.canvas = new p5(this.props.sketch, this.el);
            // window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateCanvasDimensions);
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps() {

        }

        updateCanvasDimensions(){
            this.setState({ parentW: window.innerWidth })
        }

        render() {
            return <div className="sketch" ref={(el)=>{this.el = el}}></div>;
        }

    }

    export default P5Wrapper;
```

THE SKETCH

```
export default function Oogle(p){
    let parentW = document.querySelector(".oogle").clientWidth;
    let parentH = document.querySelector(".oogle").clientHeight;
    let cnv = null;


    p.setup = function(){
        cnv = p.createCanvas(parentW, parentH);
        // mic = new p5.AudioIn();
        // mic.start();
        // fft = p.FFT();
        // fft.setInput(mic);
    }

    p.draw = function(){
        let backgroundColor = p.color('rgb(111, 77, 111)');
        // window.addEventListener("resize", updateCanvasDimensions);
        parentW = document.querySelector(".oogle").clientWidth;
        parentH = document.querySelector(".oogle").clientHeight;
        p.background(backgroundColor);

        // var spectrum = fft.analyze();
        // p.print(spectrum);
        // p.ellipse(spectrum[20] += 20, spectrum[20] += 20, spectrum[0] += 200, spectrum[15]);

        // p.beginShape();
        // for (i = 0; i < spectrum.length; i++) {
        //     p.vertex(i, map(spectrum[i] += 20, 0, 255, height, 0));
        // }
        // p.endShape();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Im dealing with the same exact issue, would love to use p5sound with React but the way that React uses the DOM is complicating things, even in instance mode.

Comment: Having the same issue, importing an addon `import * as p5DOM from 'p5/lib/addons/p5.dom'` will throw no errors but will return an empty object.

Comment: solved by anyone or not

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem faced by many...
I'm using react-p5-wrapper and have similar problems too.

https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper/issues/61

I have a workaround that only works on function calls.
I added `window.p5 = p5` after calling `import * as p5 from "p5"`

```
import * as ml5 from "ml5"
window.p5 = p5
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound"
```

Then I'll be able to use the p5.loadSound() function. However if I try to use new p5.Envelope() constructor it'll still throw me an error.

```
export default function sketch(p5) {
    p5.setup = () => {
        p5.createCanvas(400, 400)
        song = p5.loadSound(url("./assets/hurry.mp3")) // Will work
        env = new p5.Envelope() // Will error
...
```

So if it's just simple load and play a sound then this "hack" will work but if you need to use the constructor then it'll fail.

Update: you just need to change `p5.Envelope() to p5.constructor.Envelope()` !!!

Comment: So, is it not possible to use `p5.fft()`?